# My Xcode iPhone 6s simulator keeps showing a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

If someone can help me, it would be awesome because I am on this for weeks. I am using Xcode 4.6.3 and whenever I try to run the iPhone 6.1 simulator, it always shows a black screen, when it's supposed to show a grey screen with a Label and a button, see:

[image: Pic]

[image: Pic]

Also, whenever I run it, it sometimes takes more than 10 seconds to run. Here are the things I tried to do but didn't work:

1. Reset simulator Content and Settings
2. Clear Cache

I also tried to do this in the ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)loadView()
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

But nothing happened.

This is very annoying, because I really want to make apps, but not with a black screen

Comment: Really? Xcode 4? That can't be right.

Comment: Set the background color in `viewDidLoad`. Your misuse of `loadView` will actually make things worse.

Comment: using storyboard ?

Comment: Xcode 4.6.3... Why?

Comment: I have an old 10.7.5 Mac

Comment: Yeah I’m trying to use storyboard, and there is this course I’m taking about IOS app developement and in that course they used Xcode 4, but they didn’t have a black screen